# scroll to top event not work at one case ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pre append some text when the user goes to top  of contents of div, but I am facing one issue if there is no scrollable data in div. How to get that event (if user swipes or drags the unscrollable  data)?

I will explain again.

http://jsfiddle.net/d9584/13/
in this fiddle data is scrollable (when user scroll to top it pre append the text in span).

same functionality does not work when there is no scrollable data 
http://jsfiddle.net/d9584/14/

can we get an event if the user drags or scrolls the div that content (if there is no scrollable div contend).

I want to use some use some concept if there scrollable content it call this function

```
$("#contend").scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
        $("#pre").prepend("naveen ");
    }
});
```

if there is no scrollable call another

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do it like:
with scroll: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d9584/15/)**

without scroll by click: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d9584/16/)**

We check if the div has not scroll-y by this condition: `if($(this)[0].scrollHeight <= $(this).height())`. so if it doesn't have. We append by click.

```
$("#contend").click(function () {
    if ( $(this)[0].scrollHeight <= $(this).height() ) {
        $("#pre").prepend("naveen ");
    }
});

$("#contend").scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
        $("#pre").prepend("naveen ");
    }
});
```